Problemas con Referencias en Visual Studio 2022
Tengo 2 dias tratando de solventar un problema de referencias rotas

Ya he reinstalado y restaurado las referencias desde la consoloda de paquetes nuggets pero sigue apareciendo el icono de advertencia. Soy un programador novato y no se que otras soluciones probar. De antemano muchas gracias

Que error marca???

Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error  El proyecto "..\APITasaCambio.csproj" tiene "net6.0" como destino. No puede hacer referencia a este un proyecto con ".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" como destino. WindowsServiceTasaCambio

pero el error es mas que claro.. las referencias van a otra version.. o al reves.. las versiones son distintas.. y muy distintas.. net 6 es core... 4.8 no...

Entiendo... Como podria solventarlo?

Cambia tu tipo de proyecto o trae las referencias que corresponden... no se cual de ellas esta confundido.. no se porque estas trayendo librerias viejas...

Te comento, tengo una solucion con 4 proyectos dentro. Siempre los trabaje de la misma manera y nunca hubo problema. Todo empezo cuando quise reorganizar las carpetas raiz de los proyectos en un mismo directorio para subir toda la solucion al GIT dela compañia. Hice commit y subi todos los proyectos. Al volver a abrir la solucion me topo con el mencionado error de las referencias.

Alguien cambio el target de ese proyecto.. tendrias que actualizar las librerias de ese proyecto...
